# Why can't I resize a bitmap to the size of an ImageView?

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

```
bitmap.setWidth(imageview.getWidth());
bitmap.setHeight(imageview.getHeight());
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Why is this not working? I can load the bitmap, but i can't set the size to the size of an `imagebutton` or `imageview`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your bitmap fits to your ImageView, you can use one of the following ways.
**1. Change in xml layout file**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

**2. Change in java code**

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that,